# "Seriously speaking" or just "seriously"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

Is the expression *seriously speaking* redundant? For example:

> [A asks a question]
>
> [B replies with a joke]
>
> [A and B laugh]
>
> B: No, seriously (speaking), I came to visit my mom.

I think writing "No, seriously..." would imply that A is not believing what B is saying (which isn't the case in my example above).

I'm not very sure, though.

I also thought of the expression *talking seriously*. But I think I'm translating directly from Spanish (hablando enserio).

Comment: It's not redundant, but it would feel a little less awkward if you reversed the phrasing: "No, speaking seriously, ..."

Comment: The pragmatic marker 'seriously' is often a topic- and always a mood-change marker, but often is equivalent to 'joking apart'. 'Speak[ing] seriously' may be used this way, but as in the adverbial usage 'You must speak seriously with him' can carry a much weightier sense. AHD gives this sense for the adjective: **serious**  adj. 1. Grave in quality or manner: 'gave me a serious look'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a BrE example

- A: "What are you doing here at the hospital?"
- B: "I'm just here to pick up a nurse or two"
- [A & B laugh] *A does believe B's statement*
- B: "No, seriously, I came to visit my mum, she's dying"

But there is also the reverse

- A: "What are you doing here at the hospital?"
- B: "I came to visit my mum, she's dying"
- A: "No, seriously?" *A does believe B's statement but is taken aback*
- B:  "Nah, I'm just here to pick up a nurse or two"
- [A & B laugh]

*Seriously speaking* in not really often used in those kind of conversations but it used in other conversations.

If someone is building a house, and you give advice to them along the lines of ...

> You should be using 4x2s for the roof.

You might enhance this further by saying

> You should be using 4x2s but seriously speaking, you should be using tanalised 4x2s.

*tanalised* wood is wood that has been pressure treated with a preservative.